# How would I address QWidgets Ui when working with namespaces?

Tags: qt, qwidget

I've moved some previously working classes into a new namespace and now I've got a problem when accessing one class' `ui`.

Before it was like this:

```
//header file

namespace Ui
{
  class Setup;
}

class Setup : public QWidget
{
  // stuff
};
```

Now I do it like this:

```
//header file

namespace Ui
{
  class Setup;
}

namespace anomalyDetection
{
  class Setup : public QWidget
  {
    // stuff
  };
}
```

The bit that's troubling me is the constructor:

```
//source file

namespace anomalyDetection
{
  Setup::Setup()
  : ui(new Ui::Setup())  //here i get a C2512 'no default constructor available'
  {

  }
}
```

I've tried several constellations of describing the type, but it doesn't seem to work in any way. Is there a way of making this work?

Comment: Have you included the setup header file in the anomalyDetection implementation file?

Comment: @Merlin069: I did that, yeah. It's a problem of namespaces, I fear.

Comment: I don't doubt that, just wanted to cover the obvious first.

Comment: Another point I noticed, that I've come across before with a particular compiler, you call (new Ui::Setup()). Try removing the parenthesis for the empty parameter list, so it's (new Ui::Setup)

Comment: @Merlin069: I tried both, but that didn't change a thing. In the meantime I found the problem, which had nothing to do with the namespace at all. It was due to renaming the Setup-class, which I did before that.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason is that you declared two different classes named `Setup` in two different namespaces: `Ui` and `anomalyDetection`, and the first class `Ui::Setup` has no default constructor, and compiler detects that. You need to define `Ui::Setup` class as follows:

```
namespace Ui
{
    class Setup
    {
    public:
        Setup()
        {}
    };
}
```

Nevertheless, I don't think I understand for what purpose you design classes in this way.

Comment: Alright... it seems to work, but now I'd have to address the class as Ui::anomalyDetection::Setup. Is there a way around this? As for why the class is designed like this, that's a good question. I'm working with a relatively old codebase here, so I'd have to check if there's a better way later on. For now, I just need to get it to work, preferably without having to address it with Ui::anomalyDetection::Setup.

Comment: @bumbumfish, with the current design, there is no `Ui::anomalyDetection::Setup` class. If you want to have such class you need to define it into the nested namespaces.

Comment: You could typedef a shorter version, rather than typing Ui::anomolyDetection::Setup all the time.

Comment: @vahancho: okay, I misinterpreted your code-bit. Now I get it, makes sense. But it did work before I added namespaces, so why didn't it need the default constructor then?

Comment: @bumbumfish, I cannot tell that, because I don't see the "old" code and how `Ui::Setup` was used there.

Comment: @vahancho: The first codeblock in the my original question is the old header with which it worked. The third codeblock is how it was - and is still - used. All I did change was the namespace around the class declaration. So I'm wondering, why the sudden need for a default constructor now?

Comment: @bumbumfish: I get the same error if use `Ui::Setup()` regardless of `anomalyDetection` namespace existence.

Comment: @vahancho: That's strange. I just tested this on a new project and you're right. I wonder if maybe I unknowingly changed something else too... I'll have to look into that.

Comment: I checked some other things and it turns out this had nothing to do with the namespace. It was a leftover error from a renaming I did before that. Thanks anyway and sorry for wasting your time.